# Pylint Reports False Import Errors for Project with Nested Structure

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, warnings, pylint

My Python Chalice project is working fine, and all my tests pass, but Pylint is reporting `unresolved import` errors.

I have reproduced the error on a vanilla Python project with the following project structure:

```
myproject
    .vscode
        settings.json
    /api
        /domain
            __init__.py
            weekday.py
        __init.py
        app.py
    /tests
        /api
            /domain
                __init__.py
                test_weekday.py
            __init__.py
        __init__.py
```

`.vscode/settings.json`:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python.exe"
}
```

`weekday.py`:

```
from enum import Enum


class Weekday(Enum):
    MONDAY = 'mon'
    TUESDAY = 'tue'
    WEDNESDAY = 'wed'
    THURSDAY = 'thu'
    FRIDAY = 'fri'


class InvalidValue(Exception):
    pass


def parse(key: str) -> Weekday:
    try:
        return Weekday(key)
    except Exception as e:
        raise InvalidValue() from e
```

`app.py`:

```
from domain.weekday import Weekday


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Weekday.MONDAY.value)

    print('done!')
```

`test_weekday.py`:

```
from unittest import TestCase

from api.domain import weekday
from api.domain.weekday import Weekday


class StateTests(TestCase):
    def test_validParsing(self):
        self.assertEqual(weekday.parse('mon'), Weekday.MONDAY)
        self.assertEqual(weekday.parse('tue'), Weekday.TUESDAY)
        self.assertEqual(weekday.parse('wed'), Weekday.WEDNESDAY)
        self.assertEqual(weekday.parse('thu'), Weekday.THURSDAY)
        self.assertEqual(weekday.parse('fri'), Weekday.FRIDAY)

    def test_invalidParsing(self):
        with self.assertRaises(weekday.InvalidValue):
            weekday.parse('invalid value')
```

Below are my Python-specific VS Code settings:

```
"python.languageServer": "Microsoft",
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.linting.pylintUseMinimalCheckers": false,
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--disable=C0111"
],
"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python.exe",
"python.linting.mypyCategorySeverity.note": "Warning",
"python.linting.mypyEnabled": true
```

I run my vanilla Python app with `python api/app.py` and my tests with `python -m unittest -f`.

On my vanilla Python project above, I am getting the below errors and warnings (the tests aren't reporting any issues, which is strange):

```
app.py
    ERROR: Unable to import 'domain.weekday' pylint(import-error)
    WARNING: unresolved import 'domain.weekday' Python(unresolved-import)
```

On my Python Chalice project, I am getting the below errors and warnings:

```
app.py
    ERROR: Unable to import 'domain' pylint(import-error)
    WARNING: unresolved import 'domain' Python (unresolved-import)
test_weekday.py
    ERROR: Unable to import 'api.domain' pylint(import-error)
    ERROR: Unable to import 'api.domain.weekday' pylint(import-error)
```

Again, both apps work fine and all my tests pass.

I tried adding the following to my `.vscode/settings.json`, but it doesn't help:

```
{
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        "./api",
        "./tests"
    ],
}
```

How do I configure Pylint to work properly with this project structure?

Answer (score -1):

I created a same project as you provided the folder structure, and also the same settings. There's nothing wrong but pylint warning:

[image]

Add the following settings can disable these warnings:

```
    "python.analysis.disabled": [
        "unresolved-import",
    ],  
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "----extension-pkg-whitelist=1xml"
    ],
```

[image]

More detailed information about pylint, please refer to [Readable Pylint Messages](https://github.com/janjur/readable-pylint-messages/blob/master/README.md).

**[edit]**

Set `"python.languageServer": "Jedi",` can also disable these warnings.

OR add configuration in `launch.json`:

[image]

Comment: I don't know, disabling warnings doesn't feel right. What if a legit unresolved import occurs? Many thanks for sharing, though! :)

Comment: These warnings doesn't affect the project execution, so disabling them is okay. The another way is to change language server to Jedi, and i've edit my answer. please have a look at.

Comment: No, no. Warnings certainly do not affect project execution, but they're there for a reason. If a warning is raised, that means something is fundamentally wrong with the code. I'm looking for an answer that will ***resolve*** these false warnings as opposed to disabling them outright.

Comment: That's because these modules are not in the same folder. keep your settings still and add  `"env": {
                "PYTHONPATH":"${workspaceFolder}",
            },` in launch.json, then reload the window. this works on my machine.